# Testing an rxjs get method(service), on the component

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

The function call on the service is like so.

```
  get getLayerToEdit(): BehaviorSubject<VectorLayer> {
    return this.layerToEdit;
  }
```

Which is then invoked on the ngOnInit like so.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.annoService.getLayerToEdit.subscribe((layerToEdit: any) => {
        this.layer = layerToEdit;
        this.layerId = layerToEdit.ol_uid;
    });
```

So naturally in my test I'm wanting to see if the component.layer matches what this service returns.

Test File

```
  let component: EditFeatureComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EditFeatureComponent>;
  let mockAnnoService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getLayerToEdit', 'getCurrentAction', 'setCurrentAction']);
  let layer;
```

The first before each code block

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EditFeatureComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: AnnotationService, useValue: mockAnnoService}
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Fields required for the component
    layer = {
      layerName: 'testLayer',
      ol_uid: 1
    }
    // Create the testbed
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EditFeatureComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

And then the actual test

```
  it('Should return a layer object and have a ol_uid of 1', ()=>{
    mockAnnoService.getLayerToEdit.and.returnValue(of(layer))
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.layer).toBe(layer);
  })
```

The test returns `'this.annoService.getLayerToEdit.subscribe is not a function'`

I've also tried using subscribe rather than of.

```
mockAnnoService.getLayerToEdit.and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} })
```

I'm pretty ill informed on testing but this is the approach I'd normally take to test services but it's my first time testing a 'get' method from a service so I'm assuming that I'm going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **mockAnnoService.getLayerToEdit** is **getter** so you cannot mock it using **jasmine.createSpyObj** because it mocks only **methods** in that way.
You need to create plain object instead of mock and assign observable with needed data to the **getLayerToEdit** field.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure I follow, I've tried adding mockAnnoService.getLayerToEdit.and.returnValue(of({})) in the second beforeEach block, which yields the same result. Also seems weird to try and invoke that function in the BE rather than in my actual test?

Comment: at the beginning of beforeEach?

Comment: ok, remove that and then try to remove **fixture.detectChanges();** from your beforeEach function

Comment: Still the same result, also tried invoking component.ngOnInit rather than detect changes :/

Comment: okey, then last guess, i assume that **jasmine.createSpyObj(['getLayerToEdit', 'getCurrentAction', 'setCurrentAction']);** creates only methods, but **getLayerToEdit** is getter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187384/discussion-between-amir-arbabian-and-munerz).